# ng-repeat input with comma separator

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a string in this format

```
string = "1,3,12,33"
```

I want to simply do a ng-repeat over the values 1 3 12 33 and my code is

```
<div ng-repeat="number in string" ng-if="number!=','">
    <a class="item item-icon-right font-12">
       <b>{{number}}</b>
    </a>
</div>
```

The problem that my code shows

```
1
2
1 (should show 12)
2
3
3 (should show 33)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you will have to create an array in your controller, you won't be able to iterate over this string in the HTML in the way you are expecting, since each *character* is it's own iteration using this syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by spliting the string with the `','`

**JS:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.string = '1,3,12,33';
        $scope.arrString = new Array();
        $scope.arrString = $scope.string.split(',');
});
```

**View:**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p ng-repeat="val in arrString track by $index">
       {{val}}
    </p>
  </body>
```

Working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/pCehcPRMgwf8rOnTH2AJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to first split the string in your controller like this:

```
var numbers = string.split(",")
```

Now you have a array with that contains [1, 2, 12, 33] use this variable inside your ng-repeat